# When the input shape is incompatible, what will tensorflow actually do?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Thanks for your reading.

I train a LSTM predictor with fixed dimension `(None, 5, 2)`, and I test the predictor with smaller dimension `(None, 1, 2)`, and I got the warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 5, 2) for input Tensor("input_1_1:0", shape=(None, 5, 2), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 2).
```

**However, the results are fine.**

I just wonder what tensorflow actually do when the case happens? Say it will automatically pad zero, such that to match the dimensions?

Again, thanks for your reading and looking forward to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tensor computations are executed as a TensorFlow graph - see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs. Normally graph execution is faster.

The second dimension of LSTM is dynamic. In such cases keras have to rebuild the graph every time when the input shape changing. It is slow. If your input shape is changing frequently - graph execution could be slower than eager execution. Because of that - keras issuing a warning.

Keras don't pad your data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which help me solve the problem. The input dimension of LSTM  can vary. Thanks again for your timely answer!